# How to remove uploaded list to display in antd Upload?

Tags: reactjs, upload, chat, antd

I am using upload component in my chat application to allow user to upload their picture in chat room. But after uploading the  picture the name of file display in bottom and i want to disappear it but i couldn't. It has a showUploadList attribute but when i set it false, it doesn't work.

```
 <Upload
   action={`${url}api/v1/chat/messages/${chatID}`}
   name="billig"
   headers={{ Authorization: `Token ${token}` }}
   onChange={this.onChange}
   fileList={this.state.fileList}
   multiple="true"
   accept=".png,.jpeg"
   showUploadList="false">
```

[picture1 : before upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZDWa.png) 
[picture2 : after upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0rzT.png)

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can reproduce your problem and understand it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use

`showUploadList={false}`

## instead of

`showUploadList="false"`